Investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty kv_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (u_n+v_n)$ when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n$ does not converge
We already know that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n $ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n $ are both convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ku_n $,$\sum_{n=1}^\infty kv_n $ ($k$ is constant) and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (u_n+v_n) $ are convergent. My teacher gave me another question: What if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n $ is convergent but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n $ is not? Then what happens to the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty kv_n $ ($k$ is constant) and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (u_n+v_n) $?
I realize that I couldn't simply apply my intuition built on limited numbers to this question, but I don't have an entry point for this question. If anyone could provide me a hint or a conclusion with proof, I would be very grateful.
Update: Based on hints I've been given, I've arrived at the following conclusion: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ is convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n $ is divergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty kv_n $ (k is a constant) is divergent if k is not 0 and it's convergent if k=0, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (u_n+v_n) $  is always divergent.

Hint: take your favorite sequence that isn't summable. Does scaling matter?

A sum can be convergent or it can converge.

@Gary Sorry, I'm not a native speaker and I made a lot of grammar mistakes. Thank you for helping me correct my grammar！

@SeanRoberson Sequence that isn't summable...like 1/n？Indeed, if I multiply 1/n by k (if k is not zero)then the sum is still divergent. Thanks for your hint~

Other than the $k = 0$ case, which should be easy, try to prove the contrapositives (under the assumption that $\sum u_n$ is convergent).


Let us prove that $\sum_n kv_n$ converges if and only if $k=0$.

Suppose $k \ne 0$. As $\sum_n v_n$ diverges then $\sum_{n=1}^N v_n$ doesn't exist and $\lim_N k \sum_{n=1}^N v_n $ doesn't exist also. Hence $$\sum_n kv_n = \lim_N \sum_{n=1}^N kv_n$$
doesn't exist and $\sum_n kv_n$ diverges. If $k=0$ then obviously $\sum_n kv_n = 0$

Let us prove that $\sum_n (u_n + v_n)$ diverges.
Suppose that it converges. We have: $\sum_n (u_n + v_n)$ is convergent and $\sum_n (-1) \cdot (u_n)$ is convergent. By summing we have  $\sum_n [(u_n + v_n) + (-1) \cdot (u_n)] $ is also convergent. I.e. $\sum_n v_n$ is convergent. We got a contradiction. Hence  $\sum_n (u_n + v_n)$ diverges.

